# Laravel Eloquent where clause being ignored

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following query:

```
$owned = ['leads.user_id' => $this->crmUser->id, "leads.delegated_user_id" => null];
$delegated = ['leads.delegated_user_id' => $this->crmUser->id];

$leads = \Lead::where($owned)
        ->where("leads.status", "!=", "Archived")
        ->orWhere($delegated)
        ->where("leads.status", "!=", "Archived")
        ->rightJoin("tasks", "tasks.lead_id", "=", "leads.id")

        ->where('tasks.due_date', '<', date("F j, Y", strtotime('-10 days')))
        ->where("tasks.completed_at", null)
        ->get()->toArray();

    \Log::debug(var_export($leads, true));
```

But the...

```
->where("tasks.completed_at", null)
```

Is being ignored.  I'm a novice developer and I don't really understand why this is the case.  I thought that that clause should apply to all the logic preceding it.  Clearly I'm wrong though.

Comment: try to see what query is Eloquent building from that: dd(\Lead::where()->...*put all conditions up to the get() here*....->toSql());

Comment: 'select * from "leads" 
right join "tasks" on "tasks"."lead_id" = "leads"."id"
where ("leads"."user_id" = ? and "leads"."delegated_user_id" is null)
and "leads"."status" != ? or ("leads"."delegated_user_id" = ?)
and "leads"."status" != ? and "tasks"."due_date" < ?
and "tasks"."completed_at" is null'
I'm still not understanding why it's including those records...

Comment: What is $delegated? orWhere should take two arguments, are you not missing anything here?

Comment: it's an array.  I've edited my original question to include it.

Comment: Consider using `whereNull` instead of a plain `where`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of conditions (some repeating) and i'm not sure in what order they are supposed to be applied. My guess is that database server is having a hard time too.

You should group your conditions in cases like this. In Eloquent grouping can be implemented with anonymous functions in where() methods. If you want to apply the last condition to the whole of those preceeding it, you would do something like this:

```
\Lead::rightJoin("tasks", "tasks.lead_id", "=", "leads.id")
    ->where(function($q) use ($owned, $delegated)
    {
        $q->where($owned)
            ->orWhere($delegated)           
            ->where("leads.status", "!=", "Archived")
            ->where('tasks.due_date', '<', date("F j, Y", strtotime('-10 days')));
    })
    ->where("tasks.completed_at", null)
    ->get()->toArray();
```

Try it and adjust as needed if I didn't get the order of conditions right.

Comment: Thanks but that caused an infinite loop.  Should the function be anonymous?

Comment: Yes, it has to be anonymous. There should not be an infinite loop because there's no loop or recursion. What error exactly are you getting?

Comment: You just left off a semicolon in the inner query.  I tried to correct but stackoverflow requires edits to be at least 6 characters.  With a little bit of adjustment for my use case, this worked.  Thank you very much, Tadas.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Eloquent Syntax. Try

```
->whereNull("tasks.completed_at")
```

to verify that the field is NULL.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem but I agree.  Thanks.